# save web scraped tables in csv using rvest in R

Tags: r, rvest

I used rvest package in R to get the tables from web page . But I am getting the details not in format and I want to save them in csv file also. below is my code chunk. how to view and save the results in excel or csv format

```
url <- "https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/metals-non-ferrous/hindustancopper/HC07"
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('#mktdet_1') %>%
  html_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generalized solution for you to work with. There are multiple different ways you can parse this information and store it into a data frame or write it to a text file. It really depends on your use case. The first goal, however, is to extract each of the elements into its own element in a vector. Your code is a good start. We can build on this but adding an additional `css` selector which makes things a lot easier.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)
library(stringr)

#Define list of URL's to scrape
url_vec <- list(hindustal_copper = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/metals-non-ferrous/hindustancopper/HC07",
                reliance = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/refineries/relianceindustries/RI",
                dhcf = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/finance-housing/dewanhousingfinancecorporation/DHF")

#Define empty dataframe
result_df = data.frame(name = character(),property = character(),value = numeric())

#For each url
for(name in names(url_vec)){
  table = url_vec %>%
    .[[name]] %>%               #Extract the URL
    read_html() %>%             # Read the HTML
    html_nodes('#mktdet_1')%>%  # Extract the table ID
    html_nodes(".PA7.brdb")%>%  # Extract each of the elements in the tables
    html_text() %>%             # Convert to text
    str_replace_all("[\\\t|\\\r|\\\n]"," ") %>%   #Remove tab, return carrage and new line 
    str_squish()  # Remove White space


  text = gsub("^([a-zA-z\\(\\)%/. ]+)[0-9,\\.%]+$","\\1",table) #Extract the property elements

  value = gsub("^[a-zA-z\\(\\)%/. ]+([0-9,\\.%]+)$","\\1",table)  #Extract the numbers
  value_num = as.numeric(gsub("[%, ]","",value)) # Convert numbers in character format to numeric

  tbl = data.frame(name = rep(name,length(text)),property = text,value = value_num) #Create a temp dataframe
  result_df = rbind(result_df,tbl) #Row bind with the original dataframe

  #Deliverables are NA because they need to be extracted from the name. Use the appropriate regex to do this
}

write.csv(result_df,file = "stock_stats.csv",row.names = F)
```

The results of the table are just a vector with every element in its own index. `text` and `value` simply separates the column labels and values. You can then store this however you like depending on the use.

Comment: how to save the results into csv file?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the data. What do you want the columns to be? If it's just a question of saving it to disk just write the table variable to a text file.

Comment: I want to analyse the data so I would like to save the results into csv

Comment: You can analyse the results in many different ways. Save it to a file with write.csv() or if you want to analyse the results in R save it to an rds format. Use data.frame() to make a dataframe out of text and value shown above.

Comment: Edited the post with an updated explanation. Its more than enough for a starting point. You will need to edit the regex to extract some of the elements better as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For a full, complete answer, read my article published on:

Scraper API - [Extract Data from HTML Tables with Rvest [Export Table Data to a CSV in R]](https://www.scraperapi.com/blog/scrape-html-table-rvest/)

```
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("dplyr")
 
library("rvest")
library("dplyr")
response = read_html("http://api.scraperapi.com?api_key=51e43be283e4db2a5afb62660xxxxxxx&url=https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html")
 
tables = response %>% html_table()
table_one = tables[[1]]
 
install.packages("writexl")
library("writexl")
write_xlsx(table_one,"./html_table.csv")
```